# How to upload image files on my page using

Tags: image, upload

[image]

```
[Magento Admin Panel] CMS>Page>Contents
```

I tried to upload image using insert/edit image button, but I couldn't it.
Whenever I tried it, I got message

> The folder is prohibited to write

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Please check permission of media folder. it should have permission for write. If you able to upload images for product or category you should check `media/wysiwyg` folder

Comment: Good one @Kul sir, I hope you recognize me. :)

Comment: @KeyurShah Ofcourse . you are doing good job!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use this option for Image upload, Image(s) are saving under `media` directory.And URL becomes

`{{media url="wysiwyg/image-name.jpg"}}`

So make sure that you have proper permission on `Media` and `wysiwyg` directory(Under `Media` directory).

Comment: I solved the problem for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps you @이성준

Answer (score 0):

Please check your file/folder permissions.

Use the following command to make sure they're all in line with Magento's reccomendation:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; 
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; 
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; 
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
chmod 700 includes
chmod 600 includes/config.php
```

Also read through the [docs for permissions.](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html)